# Create web site similar to Microsoft Dynamics CRM with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, content-management-system, dynamics-crm

I'm wondering if there is any ASP template commercial or free for creating web application similar to Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
I need it for Intranet application not Internet app, since CRM SEO is very low as I think.
Thanks

Comment: You could use the CRM css in your ASP.NET website

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following link:

CRM 2011 Template  http://crm2011templates.codeplex.com/

Branding a CRM 2011 application https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmusings/archive/2012/11/13/branding-a-crm-2011-application.aspx

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb

_common/styles/fonts.css

_common/styles/global.css

_common/styles/theme.css

_common/styles/dialogs.css

_common/styles/select.css

_forms/controls/form.css

_forms/controls/controls.css

_controls/lookup/lookupdialogs.css

_grid/appgrid.css

Comment: could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618533/web-request-to-fetch-data-in-microsoft-dynamic-nav-erp